# Difference between AUFK-AUFNR and AUFK-KDAUF

Tags: sap-erp

There are two fields in the SAP table AUFK, AUFNR and KDAUF, that I cannot differentiate. I searched around in the net, and both are being referred to as "Sales Order Number".

Can somebody kindly explain what the differences are between the two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AUFNR is not the sales order number. Table AUFK stores the internal orders of the CO module, AUFNR is its number, so the internal order number. Internal order is a CO element (like a cost center), you can post on them. KDAUF is the sales order number (you can post sales orders on internal orders, this is why it is there).

Comment: I think AUFK is a PP/PI-table that holds production or process orders (header data, line items are in table AUFP). But other than that your explanation is what I would've written.

Comment: To be honest I wrote it from my head, and I can check it only tomorrow at work. However I found this link: http://www.se80.co.uk/saptables/a/aufk/aufk.htm About at the middle of the page: AUFK - order master data, AFKO - header data in PP order, AFPO - order item (but as said, I will check tomorrow)

Comment: It looks like I was right, table AUFK is in package KAUF and belongs to CO-OM-OPA (overhead cost controlling), so the internal orders are in this table (however CO and PP are integrated very closely - may be a CO internal order can be used as a PP production order as well? (Like a G/L account can be a primary cost element) - unfortunately I don't have any experience with PP)

Comment: @DirkTrilsbeek, AUFK is not PP/PP table, it is used in CO as well.